# Linear application on finite dimensional product space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, continuity, applications, dimension-theory-analysis

Consider the set of probability measure $M(X\times Y)$ on $X\times Y$ with $X$ and $Y$ finite dimensional spaces (for example euclidean or discrete space).

Consider the application $f:M(X\times Y)\to \mathbb{R}$ linear on $\mu\in M(X\times Y)$.

I know that a linear application on a finite dimensional space is always continuous. Is this correct for $f$ as well? My guess is that the set of probability measure is finite dimensional as well which lead to continuity of the application.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry I have edited my post. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: In what sense are $X$ and $Y$ finite dimensional? Because you refer to them being possibly discrete (topological, I assume) spaces, but then you refer to *linear* maps over finite dimensional vector spaces, which of course do not have a topological counterpart. And how is this finite dimension related to the $\sigma$-algebras of $X$ and $Y$ (the ones that are inherent to the definition of $M(X\times Y)$) ?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are finite dimensional in the sense of taking $X=R^n$ or $Y=R^n$ for example with $n<\infty$. Indeed for discrete topology, for example $X=\{1,...,|X|\}$. My guess was to use the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are finite dimensional then so is (is it ?) the measure on $X\times Y$ which would lead to the result of continuity of $f$

Comment: Far from the truth. The space of real/complex measures on $\mathbb R$, for example, is surely infinite dimensional and not all linear functions on it are continuous w.r.t. say, the total variation norm.

Comment: Indeed, that is why I restrict myself to finite dimensional space

Comment: @chaki chaki  $\mathbb{R}$ is a one-dimensional space. Your space of measures is *not* finite dimensional.

Comment: @chakichaki What about the $\sigma$-algebra part of my question?